# Cleaning up a repo fork

Tags: git, github

Some time ago I wanted to contribute to X project, so I did:

1. Forked X repo
2. Commited some changes (on master branch, I didn't create any new branch)
3. Opened a pull request on X repo (PR still hasn't been merged)

Now I want to contribute again, but I'm not sure if I can without messing with my existing on-goin PR. Can I somehow create a new branch, sync only this branch without affecting my changes (and PR) on master? Maybe I misunderstood some basics?

Comment: My assumption is that in your local you can see your fork repo (your _origin_), right? Given that you have _busted_ your `master` branch (it's not like it can't be fixed, nothing to be afraid), then you should create a _different_ branch for this work started from the last commit on `master` that is present in the real `master` branch from upstream. If you try with your `master`, you will include the commits that are not merged yet into upstream.... not what you want to do, I would assume.

Comment: Now, when the upstream decides to merge your PR, then you could move over your `master` branch so that it _again_ points to the same commit as the upstream.

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st PR should probably have been made using a dedicated branch but that's not a big deal.

You can create a new branch in your fork and open a PR for that branch into the original repo.

---

**How to get updates from the original repo in order to create the new branch from an up to date state?**

Assuming you are working locally with `origin` being your fork and `upstream` the original repo:

```bash
# Get updates from original repo
git fetch upstream

# Create new branch from the original repo main branch
git checkout upstream/master
git checkout -b my-new-pr-branch

# Then do your work as usual.. commits, push to origin/my-new-pr-branch typically
```

---

**How to have your fork main branch up to date?**

If your 1st PR has not received any feedback yet, I would delete it and recreate it from a proper branch.

```bash
# Create new branch from your current main branch
git checkout master
git checkout -b branch-for-the-old-pr
git push

# Create PR on GitHub for the branch and delete the previous PR using master

# Update your fork main branch
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

You can also do that once the PR is merged if you believe it will happen soon.

Comment: My PR has already received feedback and it's half-aproved, so I guess the 1st suggestion is the way

Answer (score 0):

What I do is start every PR branch at `origin/master`.

So first, in your browser, ask your fork repo to sync from the original repo.

Then, on your machine, simply say:

```
git fetch
git switch --det origin/master
```

Now you are ready to start a new branch:

```
git switch -c my-new-pr-branch
```

Comment: As others have said, the fact that you have accidentally extended _your_ `master` beyond the original repo's `master` is not a disaster; in the above code, I'm simply ignoring that fact. Indeed, personally, I would recommend just ignoring your local `master` entirely; in fact, arguably you should just delete it so you can't make this mistake; I never make a local `master` or `main` in any project that is updated via pull requests.